# How can I make Intellisense understand I'm coding for C and not C++?

Tags: visual-studio, intellisense

I'm using Visual Studio 2015. When I type class for example, there's the keyword, a code snipet for generating a basic class, etc. I don't want that. I want the environment to understand I'm coding for C and don't highlight static_cast or things like that. Is it possible?

Comment: Just giving the file a `.c` extension instead of `.cpp` should do the trick.

Comment: no, I did that. check my answer.

Comment: Setting this option changed absolutely nothing on "my" source.c file since "C" _is_ the default for .c files ;-)

Comment: you stop getting compilation errors when you type, for instance, class. Try it.

Comment: I don't get errors doing that when using a .c file, http://imgur.com/clHzDxI

Comment: weird, I get errors if I leave "default" on that option. maybe we have different visual studio versions? or different updates.

Answer (score 0):

Found it. Turned out I had to go to Project properties -> C/C++ -> advanced -> and change the option Compile As to **Compile as C Code (/TC)**